# information available after the `wait` call

Tags: c, process, system-calls, child-process

I wrote a program that verifies that the `getrusage ()` RUSAGE_CHILDREN flag retrieves certain information only about children for whom a `wait` call was made,
How can I modify the program so that it is more efficient in terms of handling errors? There is also  danger of a [2038 bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) occurring on this line: `printf (" before: user CPU seconds =% ld \ n ", (long) usg.ru_utime.tv_sec);`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include "print_rlimit.h"


int
main (void)
{
    switch (fork ()) {
        case -1:
            perror ("fork()");
            return 1;


        case 0: { // child
            time_t start, now;

            alarm (10);
            start = time (NULL);
            while (1) {
                now = time (NULL);
                if ((now - start) > 5)
                    break;
            }
            _exit (0);
        }

        default: { // parent
            int ret;
            struct rusage usg;
            pid_t pid;

            sleep (2);

            ret = getrusage (RUSAGE_CHILDREN, &usg);
            if (ret == -1) {
                perror ("getrusage()");
                return 1;
            }
            printf ("before: user CPU seconds = %ld\n", (long)usg.ru_utime.tv_sec);

            pid = wait (NULL);
            if (pid == (pid_t)-1) {
                perror ("wait()");
                return 1;
            }

            ret = getrusage (RUSAGE_CHILDREN, &usg);
            if (ret == -1) {
                perror ("getrusage()");
                return 1;
            }
            printf ("after:  user CPU seconds = %ld\n", (long)usg.ru_utime.tv_sec);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

header:

```
#ifndef _PRINT_RLIMITS
#define _PRINT_RLIMITS

void print_rlimit (int resource);

#endif
```

Comment: Are you planning to run the program for 2038 years? (actually 68 years)

Answer (score 1):

**2038 bug**

`time_t` is not specified as a `long`, so do not cast to `long` which may only be 32-bit and *narrow* the time value.

```
// printf (" before: user CPU seconds =% ld \ n ", (long) usg.ru_utime.tv_sec);
```

`time_t` is not certainly even an integer count of seconds.  A reasonable alternative is to cast to the widest integer type.  This will accommodate an implementation that uses a wider integer type for `time_t` to handle the 2038 bug.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
printf (" before: user CPU seconds = %jd\n", (intmax_t) usg.ru_utime.tv_sec);
```

**`time_t` quanta assumed**

Rather than assume `time_t` is an integer count of seconds, use standard `double difftime(time_t time1, time_t time0)` which returns a difference in seconds regardless of `time_t` encoding.

```
// (now - start) > 5
difftime(now, start) > 5.0
```

**Burning CPU**

`while (1) { now = time (NULL); ...` burns lots of CPU ticks while waiting. A more advanced idea would [sleep](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/usleep.3.html) for some time before trying again.

```
        while (1) {
            now = time (NULL);
            double diff = difftime(now, start);
            if (diff > 5) {
                break;
            }
            diff *= 1000000; // microseconds
            usleep(diff/2); // Sleep for half of that 
        }
```

A more advanced approach would use other system alarm routines.

**Missing error handling**

Below is an infinite loop should `time()` return -1 if the calendar time is not available.  To fix, test for -1.

```
        start = time (NULL);
        while (1) {
            now = time (NULL);
            if ((now - start) > 5)
                break;
        }
```

**Minor: cast needed?**

On many implementations [`pid_t`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Process-Identification.html) is a *signed integer* type so the cast is superfluous.

```
// pid == (pid_t)-1
pid == -1
```